# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key after accepting the form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have went through all other questions about this problem. Tried posted solution tens of times, none works.

I have two classes:

```
public class Player 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MinLength(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MinLength(4)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }

    public virtual Club Club { get; set; }     
}
```

And

```
public class Club 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Founded { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

In Create action method of `Player` i have:

```
 // GET: /Players/Create
    public ActionResult Create() {
        //SelectList selectList = new SelectList(db.Clubs, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.Clubs = new SelectList(db.Clubs, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: /Players/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,LastName,Birthdate,Club")] Player player) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            db.Players.Add(player);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(player);
    }
```

In the form I try I have dropdown list for to select the club in which player plays:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Club, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(player => player.Club, (SelectList)ViewBag.Clubs)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Club)
        </div>
    </div>
```

the dropdown list **is rendered correctly**, but when I accept the form I get yellow screen of death saying: `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Club'.`

Dropdown list looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlhjW.png).

Comment: Because in the POST method you return the view and have not re-assigned `ViewBag.Clubs` as you did in the GET method. The dupe explains it (you get a slightly different message because you use `DropDownList()` instead of (the preferred) `DropDownListFor()` method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke He uses `DropDownListForm()` I replicated his problem and even if I reassigned `ViewBag.Clubs` the selected value does not pass validation.

Comment: @Yoda, Thats because you cannot bind a `<select>` to a complex object which is what `Club` is (it would need to be `DropDownListFor(m => m.Club.Id, ....)` but of course that will also mean `ModelState` is invalid because the other properties of `Club` are not posted and everything fails). As always OP needs to use a view model (and the dupe shows the code for that as well)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can it be done without viewmodel? For instance by a `Tuple`?

Comment: @Yoda, No. A `Tuple` is never suitable for editing models in MVC because it does not have a parameterless constructor, so the `DefaultModelBinder` will throw an exception when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewData` only exists for the current response. When you return from the POST overload of `Create` there is nothing to populate `ViewData`.

The normal pattern in these cases is to, from the POST action, to redirect to the GET action. This avoids repeating code and ensures that the user refreshing the page does not post the previous values again.

Comment: I repeated the code in the POST method: `ViewBag.Clubs = new SelectList(db.Clubs, "Id", "Name");` but I cannot pass the validation of the form. I get messages like`The value '3' is invalid.`

Comment: @bielas Debug: see what values are coming back (and check the content of the drop down list in HTML).

Answer (score 0):

You should regenerate the SelectList upon post.  ViewBag's lifetime is per request only that's why it's already destroyed when you reached POST failure.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,LastName,Birthdate,Club")] Player player) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        db.Players.Add(player);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.Clubs = new SelectList(db.Clubs, "Id", "Name");
    return View(player);
}
```

Or you can just redirect it to your GET version so your GET action will be called which means you don't need to regenerate the list upon post.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,LastName,Birthdate,Club")] Player player) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        db.Players.Add(player);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Create", player);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, then when I choose a club from list I get validation message: `The value '3' is invalid.`